# Generic type parameters when calling non-generic trait methods

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait `Command<P>` with two functions like this:

```
trait Client<P> {}

trait Command<P> {
    fn help(&self) -> String;
    fn exec(&self, client: &dyn Client<P>) -> String;
}

struct ListCommand {}
impl<P> Command<P> for ListCommand {
    fn help(&self) -> String {
        return "This is helptext".to_string();
    }

    fn exec(&self, client: &dyn Client<P>) -> String {
        self.help()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello!");
}
```

Rust complains I can't call `self.help()` in `exec()` with the following error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src\main.rs:15:14
   |
15 |         self.help()
   |              ^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `P` declared on the trait `Command`
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8ff30a56fc6d4ae7a59792a36e09700)</sup>

How can I specify the type annotations for calling methods on `Self`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three ways:

- `Command::<P>::help(self)`
- `<Self as Command<P>>::help(self)` (or `ListCommand` instead of `Self`)
- `(self as &dyn Command<P>).help()` (I wonder if there's a variation of this that doesn't involve `dyn`.)

Comment: Notice that you can replace `()` with `P`, which is whatever `P` is... Also notice that `Command<P>` should probably actually be `Command`, while `exec` should be `exec<P>`; the problem goes away then.

Comment: Edited: Replaced `()` with `P`. (Since the call to `help` is in an `impl<P>` block, one doesn't need to write a concrete type at all.)